# Allow un-community-wiki-ising if nobody else has edited

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

I just accidentally made an answer of mine Community Wiki, thanks to sun, beer and a tablet keyboard that I'm not entirely used to.

It is presently impossible to make a CW post non-CW.

However, it would be handy if I could reverse this mistake *given that nobody else has since edited the post*, so I cannot possibly be stealing anyone else's rep through such an action.

I can think of a counter-argument which is that some people may have since upvoted my answer on the understanding that it was a CW and I wouldn't get rep from their vote; my response to that would be that people had already voted before my mistake, on the understanding that I *would* get the rep, so it all balances out. And people should be voting on the merits of the post itself, anyway, so if anyone is voting only based on CW-ness then as far as I'm concerned that's their problem. :)

Comment: Don't SO while drunk :P

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes bzzzzzzz

Comment: Getting rid of the [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23517366/backslash-and-newline-separated-by-space/) would actually be better.  Make good use of your delete vote.  You have the _power_.

Comment: Typos have never made good questions.  (Don't know if it has changed, though.)

Comment: @devnull That's one post. This is a feature request for the entire system. The merits of the question that inspired it are completely irrelevant. I quite deliberately did not link to it.

Comment: You could always flag as _other (needs ♦ moderator attention)_ and explain that community wiki-ising was unintentional.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've un-wikified your answer... please stop drinking and answering. :)

Comment: @devnull I did! Again, I thought a feature request might be a good idea for the general case.

Comment: @bluefeet lolthx :P

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Unfortunately, the post has been deleted.  You might need another flag to bring it back to life.